# MongoDB - postfix of an index which includes full text

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In a book I am reading, I met this statement:

> You cannot use a multikey field for any of the prefix or postfix index
>   fields.

The word here is about an index in which one of the fields (the middle one) is indexed as text, and the others are normal fields and indexed as non-text. So I tried this example below and in the 4th document I have put `[1,2,3,4]` for author which makes author multikey. Still, I am able to use author as a postfix index field of this index.

**(1)** This contradicts the book statement in my opinion. Could anyone explain if it's indeed a contradiction and if not, what I am missing here?

```
[test] 2014-04-29 18:12:53.329 >>> db.test005.drop();
false
[test] 2014-04-29 18:12:57.724 >>> db.test005.insert({dt:1, txt: "12345", author:"john"});
[test] 2014-04-29 18:15:32.461 >>> db.test005.insert({dt:2, txt: "78780", author:"james"});
[test] 2014-04-29 18:15:44.473 >>> db.test005.insert({dt:3, txt: "90900", author:"nick"});
[test] 2014-04-29 18:15:57.748 >>> db.test005.insert({dt:4, txt: "90444", author:[1,2,3,4]});
[test] 2014-04-29 18:16:12.210 >>> db.test005.find();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53602484d43f300330d5702e"),
        "dt" : 1,
        "txt" : "12345",
        "author" : "john"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53602490d43f300330d5702f"),
        "dt" : 2,
        "txt" : "78780",
        "author" : "james"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5360249dd43f300330d57030"),
        "dt" : 3,
        "txt" : "90900",
        "author" : "nick"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536024acd43f300330d57031"),
        "dt" : 4,
        "txt" : "90444",
        "author" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
        ]
}
[test] 2014-04-29 18:16:21.544 >>> db.test005.ensureIndex({"dt" : 1, "txt" : "text", "author" : 1});
{
        "err" : "text search not enabled",
        "code" : 16633,
        "n" : 0,
        "connectionId" : 1,
        "ok" : 1
}
[test] 2014-04-29 18:17:28.16 >>> db.adminCommand({"setParameter" : 1, "textSearchEnabled" : true})  ;
{ "was" : false, "ok" : 1 }
[test] 2014-04-29 18:22:15.316 >>> db.test005.ensureIndex({"dt" : 1, "txt" : "text", "author" : 1});
[test] 2014-04-29 18:22:19.63 >>>
```

**(2)** Another related weird thing is this error
which I am getting later on when running explain.

```
[test] 2014-04-29 18:38:24.13 >>> db.test005.find({"dt": 10, "txt": "2020", "author": "rich"}).explain();
Tue Apr 29 18:40:20.872 error: { "$err" : "assertion src\\mongo\\db\\fts\\fts_index.cpp:55" } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128
[test] 2014-04-29 18:40:20.872 >>>
```

Why am I getting this error?

**I am using MongoDB version 2.4.8.**

**EDIT:**

Here is the error from the log file which is related to item (2).

```
Sun May 04 07:49:25.193 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2972 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Programs\MongoDB\data 64-bit host=YBLAP4R25CN1
Sun May 04 07:49:25.195 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Sun May 04 07:49:25.195 [initandlisten] git version: a350fc38922fbda2cec8d5dd842237b904eafc14
Sun May 04 07:49:25.195 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun May 04 07:49:25.195 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sun May 04 07:49:25.195 [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\Programs\MongoDB\run\mongo-app.conf", dbpath: "C:\Programs\MongoDB\data", logappend: "true", logpath: "C:\Programs\MongoDB\log\mongo-app.log" }
Sun May 04 07:49:25.282 [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\Programs\MongoDB\data\journal
Sun May 04 07:49:25.283 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun May 04 07:49:25.786 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Sun May 04 07:49:25.786 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sun May 04 07:49:31.240 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54205 #1 (1 connection now open)
Sun May 04 07:49:40.823 [conn1]  test.test005 Assertion failure 0 src\mongo\db\fts\fts_index.cpp 55
Sun May 04 07:49:49.688 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(167)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(114)                          mongo::verifyFailed+0xdc
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\fts\fts_index.cpp(55)                           mongo::fts::FTSIndex::newCursor+0x3e
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\queryoptimizer.cpp(274)                         mongo::QueryPlan::newCursor+0x75
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\queryoptimizercursorimpl.cpp(492)               mongo::CursorGenerator::singlePlanCursor+0xc8
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\queryoptimizercursorimpl.cpp(525)               mongo::CursorGenerator::generate+0xad
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\queryoptimizercursorimpl.cpp(400)               mongo::NamespaceDetailsTransient::getCursor+0x6c
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ops\query.cpp(698)                              mongo::queryWithQueryOptimizer+0x1ff
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ops\query.cpp(1047)                             mongo::runQuery+0x1380
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(262)                               mongo::receivedQuery+0x35d
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(401)                               mongo::assembleResponse+0x2f0
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(194)                                     mongo::MyMessageHandler::process+0xfa
Sun May 04 07:49:49.689 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\net\message_server_port.cpp(207)              mongo::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg+0x578
Sun May 04 07:49:49.690 [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Sun May 04 07:49:49.690 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Sun May 04 07:49:49.690 [conn1] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Sun May 04 07:49:49.690 [conn1] kernel32.dll                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
Sun May 04 07:49:49.730 [conn1] assertion 0 assertion src\mongo\db\fts\fts_index.cpp:55 ns:test.test005 query:{ query: { dt: 10.0, txt: "2020", author: "rich" }, $explain: true }
Sun May 04 07:49:49.730 [conn1] query test.test005 query: { query: { dt: 10.0, txt: "2020", author: "rich" }, $explain: true } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 exception: assertion src\mongo\db\fts\fts_index.cpp:55 locks(micros) W:16500 r:8960197 reslen:79 8960ms
```

Comment: Can you post the corresponding error from your MongoD logs for the last find statement that failed?

Comment: @aks OK, the error has been posted.